# How to copy an object's field to another object's field

Tags: django, django-models, django-contenttypes

I have an activity model, which creates an activity object whenever a News object is created. The News object has its tags.

```
class Tag(models.Model):
    slug = models.SlugField()

class News(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=150)
    tags = models.ManyToManyField(Tag)
    activity = GenericRelation(Activity)

class Activity(models.Model):
    actor_type = models.ForeignKey(ContentType, related_name='actor_type_activities')
    actor_id = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    ...
    ...
    target_type = models.ForeignKey(ContentType, related_name='target_type_activities')
    target_id = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    target = GenericForeignKey('target_type', 'target_id')
    tags = models.ManyToManyField(Tag)
```

Now using signals, I tried getting the News object's tag in this way,

```
@receiver(post_save, sender=News)
def create_activity(sender, **kwargs):
    if kwargs.get('created', False):
        actor_type = ContentType.objects.get_for_model(kwargs.get('instance').user)
        actor_id = kwargs.get('instance').user.id
        target_type = ContentType.objects.get_for_model(kwargs.get('instance'))
        target_id = kwargs.get('instance').id
        ...
        ...
        # this didn't work
        tags = kwargs.get('instance').tags.all()
        # even this didn't work
        tags = target_type.get_object_for_this_type(id=target_id).tags.all()

        activity = Activity.objects.get_or_create(
            actor_type=actor_type,
            actor_id=actor_id,
            verb=verb,
            target_type=target_type,
            target_id=target_id,
            tags=tags,
            pub_date=pub_date
        )
```

But I am getting an error:

> 'tags' is an invalid keyword argument for this function

How do I copy the News object's tags to the Activity object's tags list?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it would be much cleaner to store kwargs.get('instance') in a variable and then work with that.  This will also get rid of your error. Then tags have to be assigned after the activity object is created.

```
if kwargs.get('created', False):
    news_obj = kwargs.get('instance')
    if not news_obj:
        return
    actor_type = ContentType.objects.get_for_model(news_obj.user)
    actor_id = news_obj.user.id
    target_type = ContentType.objects.get_for_model(news_obj)
    target_id = news_obj.id
    ...
    ...
    tags = news_obj.tags.all()

    activity = Activity.objects.get_or_create(
        actor_type=actor_type,
        actor_id=actor_id,
        verb=verb,
        target_type=target_type,
        target_id=target_id,
        pub_date=pub_date
    )

    activity.tags.add(*tags)
    activity.save()
```

Comment: Hi. I have changed it to your way. Now, I am not getting any errors. But the tag objects are also not assigning to the activity object after the creation of the activity. To check further, after the `activity.tags.add(*tags)` I added this line `activity.verb="changed"` and then `activity.save()`. This is changing. However the tags are not assigned to the activity.tags. What am I missing?

Comment: Hmm, I guess there could be other bugs.  I think you should try printing out tags and check if they are really there.  Then you can also try to add them one by one instead of in bulk (although in bulk is faster).  So you would replace activity.tags.add(*tags) by "for t in tags: activity.add(t)"

Comment: Yes. You are right. To be sure I did this `tags = activity.target.tags.all()` and then `activity.verb = "%s" % (tags.first())`. But instead of the getting the first tag, the verb I got was `None`.

Answer (score 0):

You should pay attention to the traceback you are getting. Even though you haven't posted it here, it would be clear from it that the error is coming when you create the Activity, not when you read the tag from News. That's because you can't pass in data for a many-to-many field when you instantiate a model - because an object needs to be saved before you can assign M2M relations to it.

You should take the `tags` line out of the `get_or_create` call, and assign them afterwards.

Comment: Hello, I took out the tags assignment from the `get_or_create` call and then assigned. But even then the activity.tags are not being assigned. To check further, after the activity.tags.add(*tags) I added this line, activity.verb="changed" and then activity.save(). This is changing. However the tags are not assigned to the activity.tags. What am I missing?